# Multiple SSH tunnel through raspberry pi?

Tags: networking, ssh, vnc, raspberry-pi, ssh-tunneling

In my home network I have a PC, raspberry pi, macbook and a few other devices which I want to access away from home.

As it stands, I have setup VNC server on my PC along with remote desktop and have changed the default ports. These ports are open on my router and redirect to the PC so that I can access them via dynamic dns.

However I was wondering if it was possible to close those open ports on the router, and instead leave only port 22 on the raspberry pi so I can use an SSH tunnel through the pi, to the PC and run VNC through that?

If so how would the command prompt look? I understand vaguely how SSH tunnels work and can use them applying to 1 remote host, i.e:

```
ssh -L 22222:localhost:5900 user@pi
```

then running `localhost:22222` in my vnc viewer will let me  connect to the pi.

Reading up on the subject suggests I could do something like `ssh -L 22222:internal_pc_ip:5900 user@pi` and run `localhost:22222` like before?

Can I do this?

Comment: I think you'll need an uppercase `-L` in your ssh command to establish tunnel.

Comment: You're right, sorry about that it completely slipped my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach looks ok to me.

> If so how would the command prompt look?

You will actually be connected to your pi after the `ssh -L` command. You will get the prompt that you have on your pi device. Keep this connection open to forward all the traffic from `localhost:5900` of your pi device to port 22222 of the device from where you are ssh'ing. To have multiple tunnels, I think you will need a new localport. So, may be replace 22222 with 33333.

Answer (score 0):

This is the command I use:
ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 -N -f -l username server_ip_address

Keep in mind you will have to add a source nat to iptables and also enable IP forwarding in the pi.